# How to select a path from Dynamics AX 2009 Form?

Tags: forms, dynamics-ax-2009

In Dynamics AX 2009 I created a wizard, and now I want to add a field to select a path from the local file system.

Since there is no special control for selecting a path, how do I achieve this?
Do I have to add a StringEdit with a special ExtendedDataType to get a path selection? I found no extended data type "path" or the like.

Or is this achieved some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sam,

You are right about the EDT.
There are many ways to this, but usually everything boils down to assigning the correct EDT to the StringEdit control. The EDTs of interest are FilePath, FileName, FileNameOpen, etc. You can get an idea of how it works by looking the DocuParameters form.

Regards,
Velislav Marinov